# Problem with index generation in texlive 2016

Tags: xetex, indexing

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt,openany]{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec,graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\newfontscript{Devanagari}{deva,dev2}
\newcommand{\arabictodevnag}[1]%
{%
  \StrSubstitute{#1}{0}{०}[\num]%
  \StrSubstitute{\num}{1}{१}[\num]%
  \StrSubstitute{\num}{2}{२}[\num]%
  \StrSubstitute{\num}{3}{३}[\num]%
  \StrSubstitute{\num}{4}{४}[\num]%
  \StrSubstitute{\num}{5}{५}[\num]%
  \StrSubstitute{\num}{6}{६}[\num]%
  \StrSubstitute{\num}{7}{७}[\num]%
  \StrSubstitute{\num}{8}{८}[\num]%
  \StrSubstitute{\num}{9}{९}%
}

\newcommand{\devanagarinumeral}[1]{%
  \devanagaridigits{\number\csname c@#1\endcsname}}

\def\goodbreak{\par\penalty-300 }

\setmainlanguage{sanskrit}
\XeTeXgenerateactualtext=1
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,AutoFakeBold=3.5,AutoFakeSlant,WordSpace=1.2]{Sanskrit 2003}

\makeindex[title=सूत्रानुक्रमणिका,program=texindy,options=-I omega -M mystyle.xdy -L hindi,columnseprule=true,columns=2]

\begin{document}

\fontsize{13}{15}\selectfont

 अथातो\index{अथातो} ब्रह्मजिज्ञासा\index{ब्रह्मजिज्ञासा}~॥१॥  जन्माद्यस्य\index{जन्माद्यस्य} यतः~॥२॥  शास्त्रयोनित्वात्\index{शास्त्रयोनित्वात्}~॥३॥  तत्तु समन्वयात्\index{समन्वयात्}~॥४॥  ईक्षतेर्नाशब्दम्\index{ईक्षतेर्नाशब्दम्}~॥५॥  गौणश्चेन्नात्मशब्दात्\index{गौणश्चेन्नात्मशब्दात्}~॥६॥  तन्निष्ठस्य\index{तन्निष्ठस्य} मोक्षोपदेशात्~॥७॥  हेयत्वावचनाच्च~॥८॥  स्वाप्ययात्~॥९॥  गतिसामान्यात्~॥१०॥  श्रुतत्वाच्च~॥११॥  आनन्दमयोऽभ्यासात्~॥१२॥  विकारशब्दान्नेति चेन्न प्राचुर्यात्~॥१३॥  तद्धेतुव्यपदेशाच्च~॥१४॥  मान्त्रवर्णिकमेव च गीयते~॥१५॥  नेतरोऽनुपपत्तेः~॥१६॥  भेदव्यपदेशाच्च~॥१७॥  कामाच्च नानुमानापेक्षा~॥१८॥  अस्मिन्नस्य च तद्योगं शास्ति~॥१९॥  अन्तस्तद्धर्मोपदेशात्~॥२०॥  भेदव्यपदेशाच्चान्यः~॥२१॥  आकाशस्तल्लिङ्गात्~॥२२॥  अत एव प्राणः~॥२३॥  ज्योतिश्चरणाभिधानात्~॥२४॥  छन्दोभिधानान्नेति चेन्न तथा चेतोर्पणनिगदात्तथाहि दर्शनम्~॥२५॥  भूतादिपादव्यपदेशोपपत्तेश्चैवम्~॥२६॥  उपदेशभेदान्नेति चेन्नोभयस्मिन्नप्यविरोधात्~॥२७॥  प्राणस्तथानुगमात्~॥२८॥  न वक्तुरात्मोपदेशादिति चेदध्यात्मसम्बन्धभूमा ह्यस्मिन्~॥२९॥  शास्त्रदृष्ट्या तूपदेशो वामदेववत्~॥३०॥  जीवमुख्यप्राणलिङ्गान्नेति चेन्नोपासात्रैविध्यादाश्रितत्वादिह तद्योगात्~॥३१॥ 

\printindex
\end{document}
```

When i run xelatex on above sample it generates file.idx file which contains index entries. When I run

```
texindy -I omega -M mystyle.xdy -L hindi test_xetex.idx
```

above command  is not  generating any error but generates following ind file.

```
\begin{theindex}
  \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
  \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
      \par\textbf{#1}\par
      \nopagebreak
  }


\end{theindex}
```

How to fix above problem

Regards

Shivashankar

Answer (score 1):

You need to request `utf8` encoding instead of `omega` input format:

```
xindy -C utf8 -L hindi -M devnumbers  test_xetex.idx
```

Because you want to use Devanagari numbers for page locations, we need to make custom Xindy module which will include macro to convert Arabic page numbers to Devanagari, `devnumbers.xdy`:

```
(require "texindy.xdy")
(markup-locref :open "\devanagaridigits{" :close "}")
(markup-locref :open "\textbf{\devanagaridigits{" :close "}}" :attr "textbf")
```

This module requires Xindy configuration for LaTeX markup, then two definitions for location markup follows, the first one is for normal index entries, the second is for `\index{term|textbf}` form, which will print the page number in the bold face.

the resulting `.ind` file:

```
 \begin{theindex}
  \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
  \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
      \par\textbf{#1}\par
      \nopagebreak
  }

  \lettergroup{अ}
  \item अथातो, \devanagaridigits{1}

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{ई}
  \item ईक्षतेर्नाशब्दम्, \devanagaridigits{1}

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{ग}
  \item गौणश्चेन्नात्मशब्दात्, \devanagaridigits{1}

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{ज}
  \item जन्माद्यस्य, \devanagaridigits{1}

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{त}
  \item तन्निष्ठस्य, \devanagaridigits{1}

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{ब}
  \item ब्रह्मजिज्ञासा, \devanagaridigits{1}

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{श}
  \item शास्त्रयोनित्वात्, \devanagaridigits{1}

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{स}
  \item समन्वयात्, \devanagaridigits{1}

\end{theindex}
```

[image]

With `-I omega` option, I've got an error:

```
sh: /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/tex2xindy -o: Adresář nebo soubor neexistuje
```

The compilation continues, but the resulting index is empty.

the compilation then continues, but the index is empty

Comment: Thank you. It is working. How to get numerals in devanagari?

Comment: @Shivashankar sure, it is possible with some Xindy configuration, see the updated answer

Comment: Thank you. Can we use `\devanagaridigits` even for numerals in other places?

Comment: @Shivashankar sure, what other places do you have in mind?

Comment: page numbers in headers and footers?